# transition matrix force ncol to equal nrows

Tags: r, matrix

I have created a transition matrix as a 'from cluster' (rows) 'to cluster' (columns) frequency. Think Markov chain.

Assume I have 5 from clusters but only 3 to clusters then I get a 5*3 transition matrix. How do a force it to be a 5*5 transition matrix? Effectively how to I show the all zero columns?

I'm after an elegant solution as this will be applied on a much larger problem involving hundreds of clusters. I am really quite unfamiliar with R Matrix's and to my knowledge I don't know of an elegant way to force number of columns to enter number of rows then impute zero's where no match except for using a for loop which my hunch is that's not the best solution.

Example code:

```
# example data
cluster_before <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
cluster_after <- c(1,2,4,4,1)

# Table output
table(cluster_before,cluster_after)
# ncol does not = nrows. I want to rectify that

# I want output to look like this:
what_I_want <- matrix(
  c(1,0,0,0,0,
    0,1,0,0,0,
    0,0,0,1,0,
    0,0,0,1,0,
    1,0,0,0,0),
  byrow=TRUE,ncol=5
)

# Possible solution. But for loop can't be best solution?
empty_mat <- matrix(0,ncol=5,nrow=5)

matrix_to_update <- empty_mat

for (i in 1:length(cluster_before)) {
val_before <- cluster_before[i]
val_after <- cluster_after[i]
matrix_to_update[val_before,val_after] <- matrix_to_update[val_before,val_after]+1
}
matrix_to_update
# What's the more elegant solution?
```

Thanks in advance for your help. It's much appreciated.

Comment: BTW, did you mean to have the rows be *from* and the columns be *to*? Usually for a Markov model, the transition matrix is such that `state_after = T * state_before`.

Comment: Yep rows from columns to: 'from cluster' (rows) 'to cluster' (columns)

Answer (score 3):

Make them `factor`s and then `table`:

```
levs <- union(cluster_before, cluster_after)
table(factor(cluster_before,levs), factor(cluster_after,levs))

#    1 2 3 4 5
#  1 1 0 0 0 0
#  2 0 1 0 0 0
#  3 0 0 0 1 0
#  4 0 0 0 1 0
#  5 1 0 0 0 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to use matrix indicies:

```
what_I_want <- matrix(0,ncol=5,nrow=5)
what_I_want[cbind(cluster_before,cluster_after)] <- 1
print(what_I_want)
##     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
##[1,]    1    0    0    0    0
##[2,]    0    1    0    0    0
##[3,]    0    0    0    1    0
##[4,]    0    0    0    1    0
##[5,]    1    0    0    0    0
```

The second line sets the elements corresponding to the row (`cluster_before`) and column (`cluster_after`) indices to `1`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks I'll have to look into matrix indicies in R. I definitely want to get more familiar with how to efficiently handle matrices in R. Indexing through cbind after creating a zero matrix is a great solution.